# I want my Flutter Application to automatically refresh variables everytime I add a new data to the SQLite Database

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried making a function that retrieves and displays the data when called.

```
refresh() async {
  Transaction1 line = await getBalance();
  AppGlobalVars.balance = double.parse(line.allowance);
  AppGlobalVars.expense = double.parse(line.spent);
}
```

I've put it on my main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  refresh();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

The purpose of this is so that it could retrieve the texts' data from the database upon launch. It works. But when I try to use refresh after adding to the database, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State management is what you need. 
provider/flutter_bloc/redux... there are many options, choose one and go with it.

Comment: Kiran, while your answer might be right, a code snippet or more information will be appreciated.